# C# : Detecting changes in an XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, diff

All,

I am getting an XML document from a device, which I have to upload to a webservice, if the XML doc changed from old one. I don't care about what has changed in the XML document, only thing I care is it changed. I poll for this document from device every 10 seconds and if it changed from old ,I upload to a webservice. I don't have a schema for this doc, so I can't serialize this doc. So in this case what is the best practice to detect that an XML document changed from a previous one. I am using C#6.0 for development.

I have seen lot of recommendations on XML diff, but I am looking for a best practice and don't want to over kill my implementation.

thanks!

Comment: How big is the document? I assume too big to use String.Equals?

Comment: @Chris Taking into account "poll for this document from device every 10 seconds" that is probably not the issue. Perhaps, there is something with serialization on the device that it may produce the same data, but with additional whitespace and different element order, and that prevents direct comparison approaches.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: This is true. I had assumed that the document was being generated by the same thing every time so that things like white space wouldn't change but you may well be right. Sometimes though people do overlook the simple options so its always worth asking.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to figure out if the XML is actually different. If you just care if the document is different from the previous fetch, compute the hash and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue using "XMLDiffPatch". It was pretty straight forward.

```
  XmlDiff xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder |
                                    XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                                    XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
  bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(originalFile, newFile,  null);
```

A good article in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use www.xmlunit.org

Specifically use the https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/Comparing-XML

XMLUnit's diff system breaks down the whole process of comparing two pieces of XML into atomic parts. Each such part is represented as a Comparison. A Comparison encapsulates a type of comparison like "the name of an XML element", "the number of child nodes" or "the value of an attribute" and the two pieces that are to be compared - those two pieces are called Details in this context and know about the DOM nodes that get compared as well as the XPath location of said nodes inside their respective documents and the value WRT to the comparisons at hand. For "the name of an XML element" or "the number of child nodes" the DOM nodes would be element nodes and the values would be the QName/XmlQualifiedName of the element or a number respectively.

A Comparison only knows what is getting compared, it doesn't judge whether the values are equal or different. This is for the DifferenceEngine or rather the DifferenceEvaluator to decide.

A Difference combines a Comparison with the DifferenceEvaluator's decision. In most situations where Difference objects are part of XMLUnit's API it is assumed the comparison has not led to an EQUAL result, hence the name.

A Diff is the overall result of comparing two pieces of XML, it is a wrapper around a potentially empty collection of Differences.

```
final String control = "<a><b attr=\"abc\"></b></a>"; 
final String test = "<a><b attr=\"xyz\"></b></a>";

Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(control))
              .withTest(Input.fromString(test))
              .build();

Assert.assertFalse(myDiff.toString(), myDiff.hasDifferences());
```

https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/DiffBuilder